# Rails dependent destroy error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, associations, dependent-destroy

I have a Rails Movie app. With, obviously, a movie table. A movie `has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy` and a comment `belongs_to :movie`.
A comment also `belongs_to :user` so when a new User comments on a movie, that comment will display on their `users#show` page.

If a *User Comments* on a *Movie*, the comment will display on their page. I can also go to `localhost:3000/comments/:id` to see that comment's show page

Now my problem is this:

If I then destroy or delete that movie with that comment, the comment doesnt actually get deleted. I can still go to `localhost:3000/comments/:id`, and if i go to the `users/:id/reviews` (where the user's comments are displayed) I get an error because that comment is still being displayed and still belongs to a movie. 
So i get an error of this sort `Unable to find Movie with id = 58`

Is there a way in the `Movies_controller.rb` `destroy action` to say when the movie is deleted, also delete all comments with `movie_id => params[:id]`

Comment: `:dependent` should be a symbol in this line: `has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy`.  If this is a typo in your actual code, fix and and see if this resolves the issue.  This thread might help you with your question about the `MoviesController#destroy` action: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547616/dependent-destroy-isnt-calling-the-destroy-method-before-the-deletion

Comment: My code isnt with me right now but I do think that in my model the colon is already there, so it was just a problem with the question and not the code. Edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way to delete comments of a movie:

```
def destroy
 @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
 @movie.comments.delete_all
 @movie.destroy
end
```

Comment: Ok so this works BUT it signs the user out. So it by destroying the movie and the comment you're also destroying the user session

Comment: this problem comes not from my code, in fact, the problem is somewhere else and I suspect this is why your dependent: :destroy didn't worked. Put your logs for the destroy movie action.

Comment: I wasnt implying that it was because of your code, but just that it triggers it. 

https://gist.github.com/mpcoding/b8c95a7103916baba3dd

Comment: show your application.html.erb, or check if you have `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>` in it.

Comment: there is an warning in your logs `WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` and I guess this might be related to this.

Comment: either way, logs clearly shows that comments are deleted and movie too.. could be some filter that you used wrong for authentication, could a wrong redirect that you do on calling destroy, etc... hard to guess, but after you fix this you can use `dependent: :destroy` again I think.